# Changing the ActionBars opacity due to the Activities view size

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I have an Activity with a SherlockMapFragment which is basically a SupportMapFragment. In it I display a map with some Markers for example gas stations. What I want is a UI that looks a bit like Google Maps for Android especially with the transparent ActionBar so you can see the map through the ActionBar. To assure this behavior i call requestWindowFeature in my Activity before i call setContentView().

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
setContentView(layout.activityLayout);
```

Important for me is that the ActionBar (I use Sherlock) is transparent but still has its actions (OptionsMenu) visible so the user can click actions on the transparent ActionBar - just like Google Maps for Android.

So far everything works and looks good. Next thing is I want to show the markers on the map in a list aswell so the user can choose what suits better for him. It is just a different presentation with the same data. The ListView is an element in the fragmentLayout.xml that I simply inflate and fill with data.

Now the problem comes:
As i did call requestWindowFeature to tell the system to use the space behind the ActionBar, it will inflate the ListView the same size and so my first element of the list is behind the ActionBar instead of below the ActionBar.

It would be perfect if I could for instance reset the behavior so my view begins behind or below the ActionBar depending on what i need.

What did i try:
1) Of course I tried to call requestWindowFeature after inflating the ListView which ends in a RuntimeException because you only can call it before setContentView()

2) I tried to set the Flag via setFeatureInt() and invalidating from within the fragment like follows:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFeatureInt(
                       Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY), 
                       R.layout.activityLayout);
super.onCreate(null);
getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.activityLayout);
vg.invalidate();
vg.requestLayout();
vg.postInvalidate();
```

It would be great if anyone could help me. If you need additional information please contact me.

Cheers
Emanuel

Comment: You can't alter Actionbar's init properties in the middle of code, but you can set top margin of `Listview` a little more than Actionbar's height.

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. I thought about doing that my self. I'm struggling with two things - 1. I think it is a bad solution and makes the code more complex to maintain and 2. I have a lot of screens where i need the opaque ActionBar. Only on the MapScreen i need it transparent. That means I need to change the behavior of the ActionBar on every other screen I wish to implement.

Comment: Or, you can create an abstract class extending Activity(or sherlock Actvity etc), do overlay stuff in its `onCreate()`. Let all other Activity classes extend this class.

Comment: Sorry, i was very busy the last days. I still got no good solution to this problem. What i did now is to set the WindowFeature Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY as described in my Question. In every Fragment, that does need an opaque ActionBar, I set a paddingTop of the ActionBars height so the content of a Fragment starts below the ActionBar. Not sure if it is worth to mark as answer because I don't really like the solution :/